# SQL combine 3 query by using same table

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have 3 queries which is shared same table, query 1 as below:

```
SELECT MAX(TranDate) AS MaxDate
FROM tblTransaction
WHERE AccNo = 12345
```

After get the max transaction date of account 12345, I want to use the max date to find the max transaction ID in query 2 as below:

```
SELECT MAX(TransactionID) AS MaxTran
FROM tblTransaction
WHERE AccNo = 12345
    AND TranDate = 'pass max tran date here'
```

After that, I want pass the max transaction ID in query 2 to query 3 as below:

```
SELECT Commission
FROM tblTransaction
WHERE AccNo = 12345
    AND TransactionID = 'pass max tranID here'
```

How to I combine these 3 queries? Thanks

Comment: So, which DBMS are you using? mysql or sql-server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that `tblTransaction` has `TransactionID` as the primary key, you can use the simpler, for **MySQL**:

```
SELECT Commission
FROM tblTransaction
WHERE AccNo = 12345
ORDER BY TranDate DESC,
         TransactionID DESC 
LIMIT 1 ;
```

and for **SQL-Server**:

```
SELECT TOP (1) Commission
FROM tblTransaction
WHERE AccNo = 12345
ORDER BY TranDate DESC,
         TransactionID DESC ;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT Commission
FROM tblTransaction
WHERE AccNo = 12345
    AND TransactionID = (
        SELECT MAX(TransactionID) AS MaxTran
        FROM tblTransaction
        WHERE AccNo = 12345
            AND TranDate = (
                SELECT MAX(TranDate) AS MaxDate
                FROM tblTransaction
                WHERE AccNo = 12345
            )
    )
```

Comment: No table alias is needed in this query

Answer (score 0):

Use this query:

```
SELECT Commission
FROM tblTransaction
WHERE AccNo = 12345
    AND TransactionID = (
        SELECT MAX(TransactionID) AS MaxTran
        FROM tblTransaction
        WHERE AccNo = 12345
            AND TranDate = (
                SELECT MAX(TranDate) AS MaxDate
                FROM tblTransaction
                WHERE AccNo = 12345
            )
      );
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply as this:

```
SELECT Commission
FROM tblTransaction
WHERE AccNo = 12345
    AND TransactionID = (
        SELECT MAX(TransactionID) AS MaxTran
        FROM tblTransaction
        WHERE AccNo = 12345
            AND TranDate = (
                SELECT MAX(TranDate) AS MaxDate
                FROM tblTransaction
                WHERE AccNo = 12345
            )
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

pleas give table alise

check below query :

```
SELECT commission
FROM tbltransaction
WHERE accno = 12345
    AND TransactionID = (
        SELECT MAX(tbl1.TransactionID) AS MaxTran
        FROM tbltransaction AS tbl1
        WHERE tbl1.accno = 12345
            AND tbl1.trandate = (
                SELECT MAX(tbl2.trandate) AS MaxDate
                FROM tbltransaction AS tbl2
                WHERE tbl2.accno = 12345
            )
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I'm partial to the WITH syntax for inner query problems.

(This solution is for sql-server, I don't even know if mysql supports this)

```
;WITH
MaxDates AS
(
    SELECT
        tblTransaction.AccNo,
        MAX(tblTransaction.TranDate) AS TranDate
    FROM
        tblTransaction
    GROUP BY
        tblTransaction.AccNo
),
MaxTransactionIDs AS
(
    SELECT
        tblTransaction.AccNo,
        MAX(tblTransaction.TransactionID) AS TransactionID
    FROM
        tblTransaction
    INNER JOIN MaxDates
        ON MaxDates.AccNo = tblTransaction.AccNo
        AND MaxDates.TranDate = tblTransaction.TranDate
    GROUP BY
        tblTransaction.AccNo, tblTransaction.TranDate
)
SELECT
    tblTransaction.*
FROM
    tblTransaction
    INNER JOIN MaxTransactionIDs
        ON MaxTransactionIDs.TransactionID = tblTransaction.TransactionID
WHERE
    tblTransaction.AccNo = 12345
```

Obviously, this is more verbose than the solutions above, but you can put this kind of query (excluding the WHERE) in a function and change the conditions as needed. You could, for example, use such a function to generate a list of all the users whose last transactions have a commission > 100.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a different approach to your question

```
SELECT 
    t1.COMISSION,
    t2.MaxTran,
    t3.MaxDate
FROM tblTransaction t1
    INNER JOIN (SELECT MAX(TransactionID) as MaxTran FROM tblTransaction) t2
          ON t1.TransactionID = t2.MaxTran
    INNER JOIN (SELECT MAX(TranDate) as MaxDate FROM tblTransaction) t3
          ON t1.TranDate = t3.MaxDate
WHERE 
    1 = 1
    AND t1.ACCNO = 12345
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t3.Commission
FROM tblTransaction t3
WHERE t3.AccNo = 12345
    AND t3.TransactionID = (
        SELECT MAX(t2.TransactionID) 
        FROM tblTransaction t2
        WHERE t2.AccNo = 12345
            AND t2.TranDate = (
                SELECT MAX(t1.TranDate) 
                FROM tblTransaction t1
                WHERE t1.AccNo = 12345
            )
    )
```